# ncurses scroll text contents of window

Tags: text, scroll, terminal, window, ncurses

I'm looking for definitive answers about scrolling methods in a window or pad using ncurses.

I would like to display a stdout stream which quickly fills the number of available lines on the screen and starts to overflow. Using stdio the terminal simply scrolls the contents. But with ncurses as far as I understand the output is only limited to the screen area. Is this entirely accurate?

Is the usual approach then to put the entire contents of stdout into a buffer and then read specific parts of the buffer into a ncurses window or pad? Which other methods are there to scroll text using ncurses?

Answer (score 2):

You may have overlooked [`scrollok`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_outopts.3x.html#h3-scrollok):

> The  **scrollok** option controls what happens when the cursor
>          of a window is  moved  off  the  edge  of  the  window  or
>          scrolling  region,  either as a result of a newline action
>          on the bottom line, or typing the last  character  of  the
>          last line.  If disabled, (*bf* is FALSE), the cursor is left
>          on the bottom line.  If enabled, (*bf* is TRUE), the  window
>          is  scrolled  up  one  line (Note that to get the physical
>          scrolling effect on the terminal, it is also necessary  to
>          call **idlok**).

Using that, you can write to any window, and have it scroll up—just like stdio.

Further reading:

- [clearok, idlok, idcok, immedok, leaveok, setscrreg,
     wsetscrreg, scrollok, nl, nonl - curses output options](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_outopts.3x.html)
- [scroll, scrl, wscrl - scroll a curses window](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_scroll.3x.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use [`scrollok`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_outopts.3x.html#h3-scrollok) like:

```
scrollok(win, TRUE);
```